# application dump files missing when run via Squish

Tags: crash-dumps, squish, windows-error-reporting

I enabled Application Crash Dumps for MyApp as follows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps

```
Key Name = MyApp.exe
- DumpFolder = %PROGRAMDATA%\MyApp\CrashDumps
- DumpType = 0
- CustomDumpFlags = 41826 (hex)
- DumpCount = 2
```

This works fine when I run my app normally, but when I run it through Squish testing automation, it does not create an application crash dump.

Is there any way to get the crash dump to be produced when run via Squish testing automation ?

(My App is a C++ app using Qt 5.5 and Squish automation for Qt.)

Comment: Try disabling the Squish crash handler by setting the environment variable SQUISH_NO_CRASHHANDLER for the Squish IDE, squishserver or the AUT (via the environment variable section in the test suite settings) to 1.

Comment: Hi frog.ca, I am unable to test your suggestion because I am at a different job now and don't have access to the same tools anymore. If someone else reads this and it works for them, please let us know via answer or comment, and I will update the question accordingly.